# Label for TextBox in ContextMenu in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I created ContextMenu with TextBox like this:

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem xMenuItem = new MenuItem();

TextBox xTextBox = new TextBox();       
xMenuItem.Header = xTextBox;

contextMenu.Items.Add(xMenuItem);
```

Everything is ok, but... i need some kind of label for that TextBox menu item.

How should I do that?

Comment: You should create a Panel (StackPanel, for example), add the Label and the TextBox to it, then assign the StackPanel to MenuItem.Header.

Comment: OK. That looks like answer... why you wrote that in comment? :)

Comment: @wdosanjos, please add your comment into an answer (preferably with some extra detail), so that Kamil can accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a Panel (StackPanel, for example), add the Label and the TextBox to it, then assign the StackPanel to MenuItem.Header.  Sample:

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem xMenuItem = new MenuItem();

StackPanel panel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };

Label label = new Label();
TextBox xTextBox = new TextBox();       

panel.Children.Add(label);
panel.Children.Add(xTextBox);

xMenuItem.Header = panel;

contextMenu.Items.Add(xMenuItem);
```

Comment: If someone wants to use that code - dont forget to set up label text :)